# Force selection by index of listbox or take apart same values

Tags: c#, wpf, select, listbox

I use textbox and button to add items to listbox:

```
if (tbName.Text != "")
{
     listBox.Items.Add(tbName.Text);
     //Let user add another new items
     tbName.Text = "";
}
```

And try to select items doing something (as I edit it).

But the trouble is the user can add same value of item, and while I try to select one of the item, it will result in failure. It will auto-select two items by same name, and the operation will be improper.

[image]

Can I use some method to force the listbox select items by index( since the index shouldn't be same)? Or how can I take apart the same value of items by programming(it won't select same item but just select what I click, is it means I should intercept the event of MouseDown or SelectChanged by select items refer to the position of mouse click, like height of the line is 18px, so if the position I click is between 18~36px, then the index of select item should be 1, and 0 is 0~18px)?

My listBox is:

```
<ListBox Height="248" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="141,223,0,0" Name="listBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="378" />
```

Comment: You're using WPF as if it were WinForms... it's not WinForms. In WPF in general, we data `Bind` properties from our code behind or view model to the UI control properties. If you had data bound a collection property to your `ListBox.ItemsSource` property and a `string` property to the `ListBox.SelectedItem` property, then you would always know which item the user selected and already have the items in your code behind. You can find out how to do this by searching the wealth of tutorials online. To get the best out of WPF, please learn how to write it.

Comment: Do you mean, if I use dataSource or binding, the selection will not by value or I can control the method of selection?

Comment: I mean that `Binding` to the `ListBox.SelectedItem` property will give you the single item that the user selected. However I believe that your duplicate value is being caused because you are adding the same object into the `ListBox.Items`... you *should* be able to fix it by creating a new `string` before adding it.

Comment: The same item add in listbox is logical opereation as same name added or same infomation added, etc. I can't force user not to add same item.
But I'll try `Binding`, thank you.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood. I am suggesting that the same .NET object has been added to the collection more than once, not that the same value has been entered by the user.

Comment: Thanks for following, I use `ObservableCollection` to `Binging` the listBox at last, and it works fine now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `ObservableCollection` finally. Although the question I still haven't been solved.

XAML :

```
            <ListBox Height="248" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="141,223,0,0" Name="listBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="378">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

And code:

```
    ObservableCollection<locateItem> locatList = new ObservableCollection<locateItem>();
    public class locateItem
    {
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Img { get; set; }
    }
```

Then

```
listBox.ItemsSource = locatList;
```

Thanks   [Sheridan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249281/sheridan)

Comment: Good. Please mark your/this answer as correct and then ask a new question if you still have problems... I'll take a look later.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you set the `SelectionMode="Single"` property of the Listbox  may help you.

Answer (score 0):

use SelectedItem or SelectedInbdex

Comment: I not sure what you mean? I hope to select item by index in default, but C# or .Net or whatever it select items by value as I see. Like the picture, if I just click one item, the item with same value will also selected.